# React native, do I need to send updates through app store?

Tags: react-native

Title pretty much explains it. Does it render JS from an external codebase so I can simply push new updates through git, or do I need to actually push the changes through App Store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my previous answer, which is getting downvoted into oblivion because it didn't predict something cool like CodePush coming to React Native :)

> React Native compiles to an iOS binary. Updates need to be sent to the
>   App Store, unless you're simply using React Native for its `WebView`
>   and rendering an existing webpage on the client.

**Updated 6/2/16**

It looks like Microsoft has a sweet plugin for CodePush [found here](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push) that lets you push changes remotely to your React Native app without having to send the update through the App Store.

Here's a quote from the README docs:

> NOTE: While Apple's developer agreement fully allows performing
>   over-the-air updates of JavaScript and assets (which is what enables
>   CodePush!), it is against their policy for an app to display an update
>   prompt. Because of this, we recommend that App Store-distributed apps
>   don't enable the updateDialog option when calling sync, whereas Google
>   Play and internally distributed apps (e.g. Enterprise, Fabric,
>   HockeyApp) can choose to enable/customize it.

Comment: React Native does not use WebView! It runs javascript on a different thread to generates native components in run time.

Comment: @Ard at the time of your comment a year ago, I was referring to the WebView component of the React Native SDK: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually working on a project (with the React Native Playground team - https://rnplay.org/about) that will allow you do live update your apps JS on the fly without submitting an update to the App Store. It's called Reploy, http://reploy.io

We will be open-sourcing the first portion of it very soon (the updater module). There will also be a service that will help you to manage your updates and even deploy your app to TestFlight and the App Store when needed (App Store updates are still needed when adding a new native module or static assets).

Also, just so you know, Apple has allowed this type of auto-updating via item 3.3.2 in the "iOS Developer Program Requirements" document, it says:

> 3.3.2 An Application may not download or install executable code. Interpreted
>   code may only be used in an Application if all scripts, code and interpreters are
>   packaged in the Application and not downloaded. **The only exception to the
>   foregoing is scripts and code downloaded and run by Apple's built-in WebKit
>   framework or JavascriptCore**, provided that such scripts and code do not change
>   the primary purpose of the Application by providing features or functionality that are
>   inconsistent with the intended and advertised purpose of the Application as
>   submitted to the App Store.

https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/information/iOS_Program_Information_4_3_15.pdf

Comment: Thank you for that reference to the rules, couldn't find it anywhere else!

Answer (score 0):

You could push an update to a remote user if you had linked to an external bundle and had the IP / correct ports forwarded, however Apple do not allow this for released AppStore apps.

For beta testing remote apps you might want to try exponent http://exp.host/

Update---
For completeness, it should be noted that if you are part of the Apple Enterprise program you do not need to publish Apps to the AppStore at all, you can post them to end users via a download link.

Answer (score 0):

I work on a project called [AppHub](http://apphub.io) that lets you update JavaScript and images without re-submitting to the App Store. The iOS SDK will be open source, but for now you can use the hosted service to manage new builds of your app.